# Actual probability in Fisher Exact test

Tags: probability, p-value, fishers-exact-test

this is my code to calculate the pvalue of the fisher test for each pair of successes from two binomial distributions (n=m=20). Number of successes from 0 to 20 so 21x21 possible combinations. In addition to the pvalue for each pair, I would like to calculate the **actual probability**, i.e. the exact probability that the statistic under consideration leads to rejection of the null hypothesis (= the probability that p-value <= alpha value, so the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis)

This is my starting code

```
n_successes <- 20

# Create a vector to store the p-values
p_values_fisher <- numeric(0)

# Iterate over all possible pairs of successes (0 to 30)
for (i in 0:n_successes) {
  for (j in 0:n_successes) {

    # Calculate the p-value using fisher.test
    p_value_fisher <- fisher.test(matrix(c(i, n_successes - i, j, n_successes - j), nrow = 2))$p.value
    
    # Append the p-values to the vector
    p_values_fisher <- c(p_values_fisher, p_value_fisher)
    
    
  }
}
```

The data are all possible pairs of values 21x21 = 441, from the combination of the two binomial populations indicating the number of successes (n1=n2=20).

The null hypothesis is H0=p1=p2 or independence of the two distributions. I would consider both cases of H1 first the two-sided alternative and then the one-sided.

With my code I calculated the pvalue for each pair and would like to find a way to calculate the actual probability for each pair.

For example, for the t statistic with m = n = 10 and a nominal level of .05, we can obtained the probability that the absolute value of the t statistic exceeds 2.101 (the 97.5th percentile of the t distribution with 18 df). This probability is the **actual significance level**

Comment: I don't understand the question: "the exact probability that the statistic under consideration leads to rejection of the null hypothesis". I think you need to state your question much more explicitly (perhaps with an example) in order to get useful help.

Comment: The probability of rejecting the null hypothesis, so the probability that p-value<= alpha. Sure, I immediately  try to modify and clarify it better

Comment: The probability that p<alpha IF...???? Under what conditions? What data? Something is missing....

Comment: I have just edited the question and I provided an example of actual probability that I would like to compute

Comment: So you are not looking for a single p-value, but a matrix of 882 p-values?